# Dropping several columns in data frame from list selection

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with dataset Titanic. I want to separate numerical columns from category columns.
I try to do this whit this lines of codes:

```py
from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

print("Numeric columns")
for column in dataset.columns:
    if is_numeric_dtype(dataset[column]):
        print(column)
print("----------------------------------")
print("Category columns")
for column in dataset.columns:
    if is_string_dtype(dataset[column]):
        print(column)
```

Output:

```
Numeric
columns
Unnamed: 0
credit_amount
installment_commitment
residence_since
age
existing_credits
num_dependents
accepted
----------------------------------
Category
columns
checking_status
duration
credit_history
purpose
savings_status
employment
personal_status
other_parties
property_magnitude
other_payment_plans
housing
job
own_telephone
foreign_worker
change_purpose
change_duration
```

So now I see clearly what is numerical category. Now I want to drop all numerical columns with names columns stored into columns_names

```py
dataset_numerical = dataset.select_dtypes(include=['int64'])
columns_names = dataset_numerical.tolist()
dataset = dataset.drop([columns_names], axis=1)
```

This is stored into columns_names

```py
['Unnamed: 0',
 'credit_amount',
 'installment_commitment',
 'residence_since',
 'age',
 'existing_credits',
 'num_dependents',
 'accepted']
```

So obviously I made mistake with last line of code so can can anybody help me how to solve this ?

I also try with this lines of codes but again nothing

```py
to_drop = columns_names
to_drop_stripped = [x.strip() for x in to_drop.split(',')]
dataset.drop(columns=to_drop_stripped)
```

At the end I expect to drop all columns which names are stored into columns_names .

Comment: What is the “obvious mistake” of your code? It might be helpful if you shared your result and expected output.

Comment: I already updated question. At the end I want to drop each columns which names are stored into list column_names

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what the issue is? Are you just trying to get in two separate lists, the categorical columns and the numerical columns?

Comment: Yes I want to drop columns with selected names from column_names. I try with code above but message is 'list' object has no attribute 'split' and split function can't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some minor tweaks are needed on your 2 chunks of codes. It's hard to be sure that this will work for you as I can't replicate exactly your dataset, but I think the below codes will work now.

```
# Code block 1
dataset_numerical = dataset.select_dtypes(include = ['int64'])
columns_names = dataset_numerical.columns.tolist()             # added the .columns
dataset= dataset.drop(columns_names, axis=1)                   # removed the [] brackets
```

---

```
# Code block 2
to_drop = columns_names
to_drop_stripped = [x.strip() for x in to_drop]     # removed .split() at the end
dataset.drop(columns=to_drop_stripped)
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Next time try posting a reproducible sample of your dataframe (like ```dataset.to_dict()```. You will get quicker and more accurate responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #Check the dtypes with
 dataset.dtypes

 #For a list of the columns with strings
 print(dataset.select_dtypes(include=object).columns.values)
 
 #Replace object with the dtype you are interested, without " "
```

Comment: Yes I can do on that way, but I want to drop from specific selection from list. So for that reason I asked question with list. Thank you for your answer

Comment: ```dataset= dataset.drop(columns_names, axis=1)``` you mean this?

Comment: Yes,this line is problem for me.Column_names is list maybe this is my problem

Comment: ```columns_names = dataset_numerical.colums.tolist()``` maybe with this